# unresolved dependency: io.swagger:swagger-core:jar in maven

Tags: java, maven, swagger, pom.xml

I face the following error when trying to build a github project:
[image]

The whole pom looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
     
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.nmdp</groupId>
<artifactId>hml-fhir</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <swagger-codegen-version>2.2.2</swagger-codegen-version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin-version>
    <mapstruct-core-version>1.2.0.Beta1</mapstruct-core-version>
    <maven-clean-plugin-version>2.6.1</maven-clean-plugin-version>
    <mongodb-version>3.4.0</mongodb-version>
    <log4j-version>1.2.17</log4j-version>
    <model-mapper-version>0.7.5</model-mapper-version>
    <nmdp-models-version>2.0.0</nmdp-models-version>
    <gson-version>2.8.0</gson-version>
    <commons-io-version>1.4</commons-io-version>
    <joda-time-version>2.9.9</joda-time-version>
    <json-version>20160212</json-version>
    <commons-lang-version>3.1</commons-lang-version>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct-core-version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-clean-plugin-version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>generated-sources/swagger/.swagger-codegen-ignore</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${mongodb-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct-core-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>${model-mapper-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.nmdp</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-hml-fhir-converter-models</artifactId>
            <version>${nmdp-models-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>${json-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
        <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.nmdp-bioinformatics</groupId>       
        <artifactId>service-hml-fhir-converter-models</artifactId>
        <version>-SNAPSHOT</version>                              //ONLY ERROR APPEARS HERE
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I don't have any experience when it comes to dependencies, but I understood some basics from this post:
[Differences between dependencyManagement and dependencies in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619598/differences-between-dependencymanagement-and-dependencies-in-maven).

I think this issued is faced here again but I couldn't translate the solution to my own issue: [Maven: package io.swagger.annotations does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52392273/maven-package-io-swagger-annotations-does-not-exist)

The maven window looks like this:

[image]

And more precisely, only one dependency seems to be problematic:

[image]

I tried to manually copy paste from the dependencyManager the two dependencies, but it didn't work.
I also tried to remove them , still without solving the issue, in case the dependency on the dependencyManager was enough.

As you can see I am also using jitpack.io to get the dependency of another project in github. Not sure if this is the best approach.

What is exactly the mistake? What am I understanding wrong, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${swagger-version} seems to be missing in the properties tag but used twice.

Try setting this property to a specific version

or removed this from both the dependencies where used. (Removing this may work in case there is a parents pom or some other jar which would be looked  up for  version by maven while building your project)

Comment: Why would it not appear with a red line in lines 91 and 96? Just removing those 2 (which are in dependencyManager) doesnt correct the error which is in dependencies. It has to be something in that project I think

Comment: @Paramar totally agree with you.